# Windows 7 VPN wont allow FTP, route FTP traffic through local network

Tags: vpn

I use a VPN on my windows 7 PC for privacy and currently route all my traffic through the VPN. This arrangement is fine and its plenty fast.

Unfortunately the VPN does not allow any FTP traffic so when I am updating websites I have to disconnect the VPN and work through my local connection.

This is annoying and cumbersome. I have read a little about split tunnelling but this is not quite what I need, and it often talks about 'internet' traffic which is not specific to certain IPs or ports.

Is it possible to route traffic on certain ports through the local connection, or is it possible to route traffic on certain IPs through the local connection using stuff built into windows 7..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first you need to do the following

Disable the remote gateway option.

These instructions are for Windows XP, but they should be reasonably similar for your VPN connection:

1. Right click the connection, and choose Properties.
2. Click "Networking" Tab
3. With TCP/IP selected, hit "Properties"
4. Click "Advanced"
5. Untick "Use default gateway on Remote network"

What this will do is forward all non VPN traffic to your internet connection, instead of attempting to use the internet connection at the remote end. This is turned on by default.

the add a static route to your VPN network

You can add a static route entry in your pc's route table

route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1

Where 10.0.0.0 is your PPTP VPN network 255.255.255.0 is your VPN mask 10.0.0.1 is your VPN gateway

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I do this it appears that NO network traffic goes through the VPN. I dont think this is quite what I want. This VPN is not used to connect to a domain or work intranet, it is used for privacy on my network connection. I want ALL the network traffic to go across the VPN apart from some FTP connections on certain WAN IPs which the VPN does not allow (as the necessary ports are not open on the VPN server). hope this makes sense. Thanks